# Is there a way to use variables in git-commit-template?

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a git commit template and I would like to use variables inside of it.

Example:

> Fix issue lalala
>
> [Ticket]  http://url-from-ticket/$TICKET

Where branch-name is `fix/DEV-001` and `$TICKET` would be `DEV-001`

Comment: The literal answer is no, but see the duplicate, which lets you change it to yes.